# Enforcing Event Sourcing schema on Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

To be clear, I am not trying to use Kafka as the data store for event sourcing, merely to replicate events.

The [Confluent Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/) for Kafka seems very interesting in that it can validate the schema for messages sent by producers to a topic. However, from what I understand it treats each topic like a container file - one schema per topic.

This restriction doesn't work for an event source stream where for a single aggregate like `File` you will have multiple message schemas: `FileCreated`, `FileMoved`, `FileCopied`, `FileDeleted`. Putting each of these on a separate topic would be complicated and error prone.

Does there exist a tool like Schema Registry which supports multiple schemas for the same topic?

**Update**

To clarify, each of the messages above would have a different schema. For example:

`FileCreated`:

```
{
  type: "record",
  name: "FileCreated",
  fields: [
    { name: "id", type: "string" },
    { name: "name", type: "string" },
    { name: "path", type: "string" },
    { name: "size", type: "string" },
    { name: "mimeType", type": "string" },
    { name: "user", type: "string" },
    { name: "date", type: "long" }
  ]
}
```

`FileMoved`:

```
{
  type: "record",
  name: "FileMoved",
  fields: [
    { name: "id", type: "string" },
    { name: "from", type: "string" },
    { name: "to", type: "string" },
    { name: "date", type: "long" },
    { naem: "user", type: "string" }
  ]
}
```

`FileDeleted`:

```
{ 
  type: "record",
  name: "FileDeleted",
  fields: [
    { name: "id", type: "string" },
    { name: "date", type: "long" },
    { name: "user", type: "string" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: same question, is there a way to specify "oneOf" in json for avro schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Confluent Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/) does in fact support multiple schemas for the same topic.

That said, the best practice is to not use the same topic for different types of data -- say, you typically shouldn't write page view events and user profile updates into the same topic.

A common example to use multiple schemas for the same topic is to allow for schema evolution, e.g. to start with a basic schema for user profiles (e.g. just username and age), which subsequently will be enhanced to a more full-fledged schema for user profiles (username, age, geo-region, preferred language, date of last visit, ...).

Whether or not you want to store `FileCreated`, `FileMoved`, `FileCopied`, `FileDeleted` into the same topic is up to you.  In either case Confluent Schema Registry does allow you to manage the corresponding schemas ([see docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/index.html)).

More specific docs pointers:

- [Register a new schema](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html#post--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions).  To register new/multiple schemas under the same subject you simply need to, well, register them via the corresponding API call.  Note that registering a new schema (i.e. when an initial schema was already registered with a subject) may fail depending on Avro compatibility settings, see next point.
- [Defining Avro compatibility settings for schemas](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html#config) (globally, or for schemas that are registered for the same subject/topic).  See e.g. `GET /config/(string: subject)`, which returns the (Avro schema) compatibility level for a subject.

Quoting:

> A schema should be compatible with the previously registered schemas (if there are any) as per the configured compatibility level. The configured compatibility level can be obtained by issuing a `GET /config/(string: subject)`. If that returns null, then `GET /config`.

Also, [valid (Avro schema) compatibility settings](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html#compatibility) are: `NONE, FULL, FORWARD, BACKWARD`.  So if you really wanted to store, say, completely different data types in the same Kafka topic, you should (a) set the Avro schema compatibility for the corresponding subject/topic to `NONE` and (b) register the relevant Avro schema(s) for each data type under that subject/topic.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific link to where in the docs this functionality is supported? Simply reading through the [Quickstart](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/quickstart.html#quickstart), step 7 demonstrates how a second schema which isn't compatible with the first is rejected. Is there a specific API or configuration setting which allows multiple schemas to be registered for the same topic?

Comment: @MarkJMiller: Edited my answer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. It would be nice if Schema Registry allowed for enforcing schemas in an event sourcing scenario - especially since this is a [specific use case](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#uses_eventsourcing) called out by the Kafka docs. The ability to enforce version compatibility would be nice in these scenarios.

Comment: Mind elaborating in which way schema version compatibility, and its enforcement, would be different in the case of event sourcing from what schema registry already provides in this regard?

Comment: Event sourcing uses an ordered log of heterogeneous messages (like my example above). If you split that log by message type to enable `BACKWARD` compatibility you loose the order. If you want to keep the order you're required to set the subject's compatibility to `NONE`. I just want to limit a subject to a list of configured schemas, but I would also like to ensure that a new version of a schema is backward compatible.

Comment: It might work something like: 1) manually register schema => validate that new schema is backward compatible; 2) Link multiple schemas to a subject; 3) when producer writes a message the schema id must match one of the schemas linked to that subject;

Comment: I think event sourcing does not necessarily require an ordered log of heterogeneous messages in the sense that the ordering is retained/achieved solely by how/where the messages are being stored.  If you store messages along with an event-time timestamp (i.e. when the event was originally created), for example, you may be able to reconstruct the original ordering during processing (e.g. when doing joins across two different event logs, where each event log has a different message type).  But I see your point about how to model your schema requirements.

Comment: That's a workable solution although not optimal. I'd prefer to implement a single solution on the server to implementing a consumer-side solution. We'd have to do that for every platform we use (JVM, CLR, Go, C, Javascript). But at least that's do-able.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll "into the same topic is up to you" ... wouldn't storing them in different topic _and/or_ partitions mess up the ordering, such a that a FileDeleted could reach the consumer before FileCreated?

Comment: Consumers gets stopped due to failing deserialisation if the consumer don’t have the specific schema e.g consumer is only interested in ‘FileMoved’  it will fail deserialisation if the other schemas aren’t present on consumer. This further complicates things as we might miss a legit event due to deserialisation failure if we consume message and only log it.